# Ignore parent class' method in unit testing with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following class which I try to test:

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB {
  ...
  public String methodToBeTested(){
    methodA1();
    methodB();
    return something;
  }
  ...
}
```

The `methodB` is parent class's method. I want to ignore this method or just stub it. I'm trying the following more and less:

```
public class TestClassA{
  @Mock
  ClassB instanceB;

  public String testTheMethodToBeTested{
    doNothing().when(instanceB).methodB();
    ClassA instanceA = new ClassA();
    String result = instanceA.methodToBeTested();
    String expected = "foo"
    assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
  }
  ...
}
```

However I see that `methodB` still is being executed. However in `ClassA` if I declare a classB variable and it's setter;  and instead of `methodB()` write `classB.methodB()` my tests executes. But I am asked to not change the code being tested. Is there any way to test `ClassA` ?

Comment: So you create a mock of `ClassB` and then an instance of `ClassA` ... why do you expect the mock of `ClassB` has a relation to your instance of `ClassA`? Just create a spy for `ClassA` and when use `doNothing().when(instanceA).methodB();`.

Comment: I am very very new to unit testing and java so I didn''t expect nothing but a miracle due to despair. I'll give a try what you've recommended. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hint: your code is a good example why many people claim that you should prefer composition over inheritance. If your class A contained a B (instead of extending it) then you could use dependency injection and insert a mocked B object into A for testing ... and you wouldn't need to get into the Spy-business. I am not saying that your design is intrinsically wrong; but probably worth reviewing it with your peers.

Comment: @Jägermeister Thank you very much for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Spy` (http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13).

```
public class TestClassA{

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Spy
  ClassA instanceA;

  public String testTheMethodToBeTested{
    doNothing().when(instanceA).methodB();
    String result = instanceA.methodToBeTested();
    String expected = "foo"
    assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
  }
  ...
}
```

You are not instantiating an instance of `ClassB` because of inheritance, but `Mockito` lets you spy on real objects too.

Comment: I forgot `@Rule`, added it now. Can you try again? The same sample works for me

Comment: Looks like the constructor call of instanceA (should be `@Spy
  ClassA instanceA = new ClassA();`) is missing in the answer code. Or just drop the annotations and the rule, and use `ClassA instanceA = Mockito.spy(new ClassA());`